# Log date & time [...] in sheet2, when editing a cell in a specified range in sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet1 looking like this

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4HUV6HI.jpg]

running this code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer

Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:K10"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 11

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

What it does so far:

- when I edit anything in range `B2:K10` it adds the date & time on the right side of the table

What I need:

- when I edit anything in the range specified above, log the date & time plus the corresponding step & item, all into `Sheet2` starting from `A2`

Expected result:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/0gpNbhi.jpg]

And keep adding below last row over and over, never erase a record if a value is deleted from a cell in `Sheet1`. Will delete records manually if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim nextRow As Long

Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:K10"), Target)

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
            nextRow = Log.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Log.Cells(nextRow, 1) = Me.Cells(rng.Row, 1)
            Log.Cells(nextRow, 2) = Me.Cells(1, rng.Column)
            Log.Cells(nextRow, 3) = Now
            Log.Cells(nextRow, 3).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

The code identifies the row number of the next empty row in Sheet 2, then writes the values into the first three cells of that row.

Edit: After seeing your edits to the code: You don't need to go through the hassle of declaring a worksheet variable and then setting it to the sheet. Instead, use the `(Name)` property to give the sheet a name, then you can access it from anywhere in the code via this name. I adjusted the code to reflect this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, Teylyn. The code works perfectly, however, I did a small edit to make the sheet selectable by name as the workbook I'll integrate this into, has a lot of sheets and the log one is not 2nd (I'm still at very beginning with VBA so I hope the edit is alright).

Comment: I added some code efficiencies and explanations to my answer.